# How to add option values on silviomoreto's Bootstrap-Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used silviomoreto's bootstrap-select but I'm having problems.
I have 2 Dropdowns (Select) a Region dropdown and Cities. Now, I have a jquery onchange function, the function will change the values in the cities dropdown depending on the region selected. Here's my code:

```
<select id="region" class="selectpicker"></select>
<select id="cities" class="selectpicker"></select>

$("#region").on('change', function () {
   $("#cities").html('<option>city1</option><option>city2</option>');
});
```

The problem is I think the compatibility? When I removed the class="selectpicker" it works fine, but I can't remove it because I used it for my dropdown ui. I checked the documentation in here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ but I can't find relevant answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try `selectpicker('refresh')`.

### [refresh()](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)

> To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate
>   the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the
>   new state. **This is necessary when removing or adding options**, or when
>   disabling/enabling a select **via JavaScript**.

Snippet

```
$("#cities")
   .html('<option>city1</option><option>city2</option>')
   .selectpicker('refresh');
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/nr54vx7b/

Comment: I can not get it running for my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191920/ajax-does-not-work-with-bootstrap-select).

Comment: I checked the jsfiddle you supplied and it doesn't work either

Comment: that was because the jsfiddle css and js links were broken. updated fiddle

Comment: Oh man You're a legend. I was about to hit my head on wall. then see your answer you saved me

Comment: Ajax binding for my dropdown works fine. But if the bound dropdown postsback it gives me error. System.Web.HttpException at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath). Any idea why i could be getting this?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve created an example of creating a dynamic drop-down menu with grouped options by taking the data from an array. I hope it helps

```js
// Example data Array list
namespace_list = [
    ['test1-c1', 'test2-c1', 'test3-c1', 'test4-c1', 'test5-c1', 'test6-c1'],
    ['test1-c2', 'test2-c2', 'test3-c2', 'test4-c2', 'test5-c2', 'test6-c2']
]


$('#pod_dropdown').selectpicker();

// Delete old options of the dropdown 
$('#pod_dropdown').find('option').remove();

// Selecting selectpicker dropdown
select = document.getElementById('pod_dropdown');

for (let namespace of namespace_list) {

    // Generating group name
    namespace_name = namespace[0].slice(6, 8)+'-title'

    // Creating the optiongroup

    var optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
    optgroup.id = namespace_name;
    optgroup.label = namespace_name
    // Appending optiongroup to the dropdown
    select.appendChild(optgroup);

    // Selecting the optiongroup 
    optiongroup = document.getElementById(namespace_name);

    for (let pod of namespace) {

        // Creating the options of the optiongroup 
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = pod;
        opt.innerHTML = pod;
        // Appending the option to the optiongroup
        optiongroup.appendChild(opt);

    }

}
// Refresh the dropdwon menu
$('#pod_dropdown').selectpicker("refresh");



// Getting the value after selecting it in the UI and unselect the dropdown

function filterpod() {
    let pod = $('#pod_dropdown').val().toString();
    console.log(pod)

}
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- multi select dropdown -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Creatting the dropdown -->
    <select id="pod_dropdown" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-sm" multiple data-live-search="true" data-width="auto"></select>
    
    <!-- Calling the function filterpod when hide dropdown after select option -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#pod_dropdown').on('hide.bs.select', function(e) {filterpod();});
    </script>
```